# howto compile cryptopp 5.6.2 with mingw

Tags: c++, windows-xp, mingw, shared-libraries, crypto++

I am trying to build cryptopp 5.6.1 with mingw 4.8.1 (sjlj). I've changed GNUMakefile from [Crypto++ & MinGW](https://sites.google.com/site/ievgensychov/cryptopp)

But there are several issue:

- I've compile error if I try to build it as shared library;
- On my machine it works (intel i5 (2nd generation) with Windows 7 ) but on Windows Xp on an Intel atom D2500 an error occured (no entry point for memmove_s in msvcrt.dll )

When I try to build as shared library I've the following error:

```
make dll
make: *** No rule to make target 'cryptopp.dll', needed by 'cryptest.import.exe'. Stop.
make libcryptopp.dll
// ...
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c hex.cpp -o hex.export.o
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c hmac.cpp -o hmac.export.o
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c integer.cpp -o integer.export.o
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c iterhash.cpp -o iterhash.export.o
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c misc.cpp -o misc.export.o
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c modes.cpp -o modes.export.o
make: *** No rule to make target 'modexppc.export.o', needed by 'libcryptopp.dll'.  Stop.
```

Does someone has compiled succeful crypto++ with mingw 4.8.1? This is the snippet of my makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -O3 -m32 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3
ARFLAGS = rc
LDLIBS += -lws2_32
LDFLAGS =
MKDIR = mkdir
CP = copy

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
# test.o needs to be after bench.o for cygwin 1.1.4 (possible ld bug?)
TESTOBJS = bench.o bench2.o test.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o adhoc.o datatest.o regtest.o fipsalgt.o dlltest.o
LIBOBJS = $(filter-out $(TESTOBJS),$(OBJS))

DLLSRCS = algebra.cpp algparam.cpp asn.cpp basecode.cpp cbcmac.cpp channels.cpp cryptlib.cpp des.cpp dessp.cpp dh.cpp dll.cpp dsa.cpp ec2n.cpp eccrypto.cpp ecp.cpp eprecomp.cpp files.cpp filters.cpp fips140.cpp fipstest.cpp gf2n.cpp gfpcrypt.cpp hex.cpp hmac.cpp integer.cpp iterhash.cpp misc.cpp modes.cpp modexppc.cpp mqueue.cpp nbtheory.cpp oaep.cpp osrng.cpp pch.cpp pkcspad.cpp pubkey.cpp queue.cpp randpool.cpp rdtables.cpp rijndael.cpp rng.cpp rsa.cpp sha.cpp simple.cpp skipjack.cpp strciphr.cpp trdlocal.cpp
DLLOBJS = $(DLLSRCS:.cpp=.export.o)
LIBIMPORTOBJS = $(LIBOBJS:.o=.import.o)
TESTIMPORTOBJS = $(TESTOBJS:.o=.import.o)
DLLTESTOBJS = dlltest.dllonly.o

lib: libcryptopp.a

all: cryptest.exe

test: cryptest.exe
    cryptest.exe v

install: lib
    $(CP) *.h include\cryptopp
    $(CP) *.a lib

clean:
    del cryptest.exe libcryptopp.a $(LIBOBJS) $(TESTOBJS) cryptopp.dll libcryptopp.dll.a libcryptopp.import.a cryptest.import.exe dlltest.exe $(DLLOBJS) $(LIBIMPORTOBJS) $(TESTIMPORTOBJS) $(DLLTESTOBJS)

libcryptopp.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBOBJS)

libcryptopp.so: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(LIBOBJS)

cryptest.exe: libcryptopp.a $(TESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

nolib: $(OBJS)      # makes it faster to test changes
    $(CXX) -o ct $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

dll: cryptest.import.exe dlltest.exe

libcryptopp.dll: $(DLLOBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLOBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -Wl,--out-implib=libcryptopp.dll.a

libcryptopp.import.a: $(LIBIMPORTOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBIMPORTOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@

cryptest.import.exe: cryptopp.dll libcryptopp.import.a $(TESTIMPORTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTIMPORTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp.dll -lcryptopp.import $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

dlltest.exe: cryptopp.dll $(DLLTESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLTESTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp.dll $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

%.dllonly.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_DLL_ONLY -c $< -o $@

%.import.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_IMPORTS -c $< -o $@

%.export.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

**Edit**

To let it work I've forced the funcion memmove_s defined in misc.h (of cryptopp) to be defined inlined and now works also on windows xp (where memmove_s is not defined in msvcrt.dll).

**Question:** Can I change the mscvrt.dll of windows xp with one defined on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to build it is using qmake:

- I removed GNUMakefile,
- qmake -project
- I open the pro file into QtCreator, changed `TEMPLATE` to `lib` and added ws2_32 to lib

The pro file now looks something this

```
TEMPLATE = lib
INCLUDEPATH += .
CONFIG -= qt
HEADERS += ...
SOURCES += ...

win32-g++ {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3
    LIBS += -lws2_32
}
```

It seems work.

Comment: is this 64bit or 32bit cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

it's a try

put `modexppc.cpp` to your  CRYPTOPP folder.

modexppc.cpp

```
// modexppc.cpp - written and placed in the public domain by Wei Dai

#include "pch.h"

#ifndef CRYPTOPP_IMPORTS

#include "modexppc.h"
#include "asn.h"
NAMESPACE_BEGIN(CryptoPP)


NAMESPACE_END

#endif
```

Comment: I've removed modexppc.cpp from build (changin makefile).

Comment: And why you give us (in your question) an error : `make: *** No rule to make target 'modexppc.export.o', needed by 'libcryptopp.dll'.  Stop.` . If you have removed `modexppc.cpp` from your makefile you will not get this error.

Comment: I tryed to remove later. I make several attempts

Comment: do you make a clean before every attempts and what you get with my solution ??

Comment: And what do you get with my solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I sent a [patch](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/ec1ff7764fbea4eefbb290c9ba888af3386ede8e/) fixing memmove_s in Windows XP to the MinGW developer team. It's been accepted and it will soon appear in the newer MinGW builds. By now it should be available on the CentOS 7 MinGW distribution and Fedora 21 MinGW.

Crypto++ 5.6.2 now builds fine without modification on MinGW, using make (and setting CC, CXX and PATH environment variables correctly). Tested on CentOS 7, which uses MinGW 4.9 IIRC.